# 2nd order nonhomogeneous ODE $T$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Just met a 2nd order nonhomogeneous ODE:

$$ T''(z)=\frac {6}{(1-z)^2} T(z)+\frac{2}{(1-z)^3}+\frac{10z} {(1-z)^4} $$

Does anyone has some idea of solving it?

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, I think we still need a particular solution for this nonhomogeneous equation. This is maybe the most difficult part. At this stage I cannot find a particular solution

Answer (score 1):

Consider the homogeneous problem
\begin{align}
T''-\frac{6}{(1-z)^2}T = 0.
\end{align}
Let us consider the ansatz
\begin{align}
T(z) = (1-z)^\alpha
\end{align}
then we see that
\begin{align}
\alpha(\alpha-1)(1-z)^{\alpha-2}-6(1-z)^{\alpha-2} = 0
\end{align}
which means $\alpha(\alpha-1) -6=0$. Solving for $\alpha$ show that
\begin{align}
T_1(z) = (1-z)^3 \ \ \text{ and } \ \ T_2(z) = (1-z)^{-2}
\end{align}
are solutions to the homogeneous problem.

For the particular solution, we could use the method of Green's function/ variation of parameters, i.e. 
\begin{align}
T_p(z) = -T_1(z) \int^z_0 \frac{T_2(s)f(s)}{W[T_1, T_2](s)}\ ds+T_2(z)\int^z_0 \frac{T_1(s)f(s)}{W[T_1, T_2](s)}\ ds
\end{align}
where $f(z)$ is the inhomogeneous term in your equation.

Comment: Hi, thanks quite a lot. I will try it